# Synchronization Central database with multiple local database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, synchronization

I have to develop a Project with php mysql for sales management system.There are many

outlet.  I want to keep a databse centrally and every outlet have a databse locally. user

entry data to local databse. after a while local data can be uploaded to central databse.

Local data will go to central database, but central data will not go to local database. 
what will be the procedure for that. (e.g: Synchronization, Replication)

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use syncronisation or replication. I would use an import/export mechanism.

Write a little tool which will export the last day/week/month and than send it with an secure line to your main database for import.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the specs of your project (size of data, longevity of data, frequency of sync, etc.) you might have to implement a one-way synchronization. E.g. your clients will upload data incrementally where only new changes (no need to re-send all information on each sync) are uploaded to the server.
You can achieve this in various ways. The simple way is uploading your data to the server and removing them from the local storage. If your clients need to keep the uploaded data then introduce the additional field “Dirty” in your tables on the client side and use it for designating the new changes. 
Recently I blogged about [bi-directional sync algorithm](http://havrl.blogspot.ie/2013/08/synchronization-algorithm-for.html), which includes the upload changes functionality using dirty field, which might be helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe SymmetricDS (http://www.symmetricds.org) can solve your problem. We're having a similar problem and we've decided to use it.